Fail to run a Fastify/ts app bundled by Webpack: "TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Serializer' of 'dependencies' as it is undefined."
I develop an app with node.js Fastify framework (typescript, ES syntax). I use Webpack to bundle the app and to compile typescript. I want to compile to commonjs to prevent compatibility issues. The app bundles successfully, but when I try to run the resulting bundle.cjs file, I get the following error:
/dist$ node bundle.cjs
/home/myzader/vc-app/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/error-serializer.js:7
  const { Serializer, Validator } = dependencies
          ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Serializer' of 'dependencies' as it is undefined.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myzader/vc-app/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/error-serializer.js:7:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myzader/vc-app/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/error-handler.js:20:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)

webpack.config.js:
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './app.ts',
  target: 'node',  // Still targeting Node.js
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.mjs'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.cjs',
    library: {
      type: 'commonjs2'  // Ensures the output is compatible with CommonJS
    }
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    allowlist: ['fast-json-stringify']
  })], 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                modules: 'commonjs',
                targets: { node: 'current' }
              }],
              '@babel/preset-typescript'
            ],
            sourceMaps: 'inline',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        use: 'node-loader'
    }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    process.env.CLEAR_CACHE === 'true' ? new CleanWebpackPlugin() : () => {},
    // other plugins...
  ],
  stats: {
    all: true,
    errors: true,
    errorDetails: true,
    warnings: true,
    moduleTrace: true,
    reasons: true,
    colors: true,
  },
};
module.exports = config;"

what is wrong with configs? Thank you!
